# Confuse with SQL ALL function with HAVING COUNT(*) >=

Tags: mysql, sql

Appreciate help to understand the concept of the result from a query 
using the ALL function. Thanks in advance!

The sample table with data =
[download employee table script](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtyLCAJDSq_qgdlQF1jt29TSnfanmg?e=hlHRQZ)
& here's the query.

```
select salary, count(*)
from employees
group by salary
having count(*) >= ALL(SELECT count(*) from employees group by salary)
```

I do not understand why would the result return only 6 rows with count of 2.

Shouldn't this `having count(*) >= ALL(SELECT count(*) from employees group by salary)`
match every row between the select sub and return row count of 994 ?

Why would `>=` return 6 rows while `=` or `>` returns 0 rows ?

A detail explanation on the logic behind this would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keypoint is `COUNT(*)` in `HAVING` clause is calculated per each group:

```
select salary, count(*)
from employees
group by salary
having count(*) >= ALL(SELECT count(*) from employees group by salary)
       -- this count changes per each salary
```

This query is quite strange. Let's get simple example with 6 rows in total:

```
salary count  
100    3
200    1
300    2


-- per each group
3 >= ALL (3,1,2)   -- only this one will match
1 >= ALL (3,1,2) 
2 >= ALL (3,1,2)
```

So effectively your query will return the row with the highest salary.

> while = or > returns 0 rows ?

```
-- always false for '=' or '>'
3 = ALL (3,1,2)
1 = ALL (3,1,2)
2 = ALL (3,1,2)
```

Comment: This helped alot.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The word ALL, which must follow a comparison operator, means "return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ALL of the values in the column that the subquery returns."

For more details, please follow the given URL:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html
```